# How to obtain SHA-1 Fingerprint for keystores which are created by Xamarin Studio?

Tags: android, xamarin, sha1, xamarin-studio, android-keystore

When you sign and distribute your Xamarin Android apps the wizard helps you create keystore for your app. However, wherever I looked on my mac I could not find the actual .keystore file anywhere. So how am I supposed to get the SHA-1 fingerprint for that keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This questions a few months old, but in the event others were stymied by this and end up here - here's instructions for mac users:

When you use the Android Signing wizard it asks for an alias and password.

Generate the SHA1 by entering by opening a terminal window and entering:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/[ALIAS]/[ALIAS].keystore -alias [ALIAS]
```

It will then prompt you for the password and if happy with that, will return certificate info and fingerprints (including the SHA1).

Note two passwords aren't needed as mentioned in the Xamarin documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/).

(And if like me you were searching in Finder for the keystore file you created with no luck, it's because the Library folder is hidden)

Comment: trying to do this but what is [ALIAS] ?

Answer (score 9):

SHA1 fingerprints are stored within the same keystore files.
Visual studio has an unique feature to open such files.
Just double click the file after creating it inside Xamarin. It will give you the SHA1 Fingerprint.

[image]

[image: check out the pic]

Comment: Could you please tell me how you get the dialog? My Archive Manager is empty.

Answer (score 4):

For windows users,

Go to this path or where ever you have your keytool.exe file

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Hold shift key and right click -> then select **Open command window here**

After commandline open paste this command

```
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Official document here - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/

Comment: One thing you missed is that you have to open command console as administrator otherwise it will given an error. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @EgeAydın no need open as administrator.. Tested in windows 10 operating system

Comment: That is weird, I have also test on Windows 10 but it was giving errors like access denied and etc. Weird.

Comment: yes weird.. In my office system I am not admin. But works for me.. thanks for info